# how to trigger the dropdown list in datagrid using jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi I have a datagrid which has a checkbox list and two dropdown list. I need to trigger them if any of them is change. I successfully trigger the checkbox. However it is failed on dropdown list box.

There are the control in  html:

```
<asp:templatecolumn >
  <headertemplate>Floor</headertemplate>
     <itemtemplate>
       <asp:dropdownlist id="dropFloorSelect" runat="server" cssclass="dropdownCSS" />
    </itemtemplate>
</asp:templatecolumn>

<asp:templatecolumn >
   <headertemplate>Room</headertemplate>
      <itemtemplate>
          <asp:dropdownlist id="dropRoomSelect" runat="server" cssclass="dropdownCSS" />
    </itemtemplate>
</asp:templatecolumn>


<asp:TemplateColumn >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chk" CssClass="BoxClass"  runat="server"/>
     </ItemTemplate>

</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

There is my function:

```
  $('.BoxClass').each(function () {
                var chkbox = this.firstElementChild;
                var chkboxID = $(chkbox).attr('id');
                $('#' + chkboxID).change(function () {
                   'do something
                });
            });

            $('.dropdownCSS').each(function () {                    
                var drpbox = this.firstElementChild;
                var drpboxID = $(drpbox).attr('id');
                $('#' + drpboxID).change(function () {

                    'do something
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the line ' var drpbox = this.firstElementChild;' to 'var drpbox = this;' and it works.